# How to make error message appear on top of form

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to create a validation error message which goes on top of HTML form. This validation error message should appear in "div" which has id=pop_up

```
<form  method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="review" onsubmit="return validate_ip()">

    <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"  placeholder="Enter your name"><br>
    <input type="Email" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Enter email id"><br>

    <div id="pop_up"></div>

    <textarea name="text" id="myself" placeholder="Say something about yourself"></textarea><br>
            <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
```

The error message should be shown using javascript. Function alert_box() should set the style for error message and show error message.

```
var val=/[\w~!#$%^&*]+[\W]+[\w~!#$%^&*]+@+[\w~!#$%^&*]+.+[\w]/;

function validate_ip(){
    var name=document.getElementById("uname").value;
    console.log(name);
    var mail=document.getElementById("mail").value;
    var testyy=val.test(mail);
    var myself=document.getElementById("myself").value;
    if (name.length<3){
        alert_box("Enter your name");
        document.getElementById('uname').focus();
        return false;
    }

    else if (!testyy){
        alert_box("Reenter Email id");
        document.getElementById("mail").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(myself.length<60)
    {
        alert_box("Atleast say 30 letters about yourself");
        document.getElementById("myself").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;                                
    }


function alert_box(a){
    var x= document.getElementById("pop_up");

    x.style.height="200px";
    x.style.width="200px";
    x.style.background="red";
    x.innerHTML=a;
}
```

I am unable to get eroor message box on top of form.
Edit : By on top, I meant error box should appear in foreground while form is in background.

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/anoopj/eykq9d1p/

Comment: Have you put the div above the form?

Comment: What error do you get in the console?

Comment: You need to use CSS positioning to get the boxes on top of each other. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831670/how-to-make-error-message-appear-on-top-of-form

Comment: Show us your CSS, maybe it's a z-indexing or positioning issue. Not sure why you're styling the `pop_up` div every time `alert_box()` is being called, when you could simply do it once in CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT:

Use Modal Box with CSS and JS. Look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

First of all put `<div id="pop_up"></div>` above `<form  method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="review" onsubmit="return validate_ip()">`

And then

```
 if (name.length<3){
        document.getElementById('pop_up').innerHTML="Enter your name";
        document.getElementById('uname').focus();
        return false;
    }

    else if (!testyy){
        document.getElementById('pop_up').innerHTML="Reenter your email";
        document.getElementById("mail").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(myself.length<60)
    {
        document.getElementById('pop_up').innerHTML="Atleast say 30 letters about yourself";
        document.getElementById("myself").focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy, but by on top, I meant error box should appear in the foreground while the form is in the background.

Comment: Add `z-index:-1` to css of the div using JS. Hope you can do that! Also remember z-index works only with positioned elements such as `position:absolute` or `position:relative`.

Comment: That did not help. the error message is not popping into the foreground.

Comment: Use modal class in CSS. I have got a perfect example for you [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

Comment: Modals are a bad design pattern due to their severe accessibility issues. If you're using modals, make sure to add all the extra features to make them accessible. Or just skip the modals once and for all and save yourself a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked to show the error in  foreground.
You can either use Bootstrap Modals or create own modals with HTML and CSS.
Here is a link to create on your own https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

link for using Bootstrap Modals
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Comment: Thank you for responses. But on top I meant on z-axis.

Comment: Thanks, buddy, but by on top, I meant error box should appear in the foreground while the form is in the background

Comment: You can use modal windows to display @AnoopJaiswal

Comment: Link only answers are considered VLQ. I suggest you bring in the relevant content from the links to ensure the answer doesn't get flagged as such. Thank you.